# How to do I create linux VM with ssh public on azure automation

Tags: linux, ssh, powershell, azure, automation

Right now, I am creating Linux VM without public key on azure automation. My aim is to create linux VM with ssh public key on azure automation. How to get ssh public key from "accets" on azure automation portal.

Also try below code:

```
$cert = Get-PfxCertificate -FilePath $certificate.authorized_keys
$sshKey = New-AzureSSHKey -PublicKey -Fingerprint $cert.Thumbprint   -Path  "/home/$un/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

Error:

> Add-AzureProvisioningConfig : Cannot bind parameter 'SSHPublicKeys'. Cannot convert the "Aazz..."

Comment: What PowerShell script would you use to do the same locally? Also, the full error message is not visible above.

Comment: @Joe Please find a code: http://serverfault.com/questions/747344/how-to-get-public-key-from-certificate-on-azure-automation

Comment: That can't be all your code. According to the other link, the error is from Add-AzureCertificate but your code doesn't include Add-AzureCertificate. Also, you should post the code here. That question has been closed as a duplicate of this.

Comment: @Joe I just want to create linux VM with SSH public key but I don't want to add local drive path on script. Can we add the the plain SSH public key on script like *$sshkey="Plainsshpublickey".